# How can i make some of the table rows not selectable in SmartTable angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I am using angularJS and smart table framework to manage my table in html:

1. The table rows are selectable using SmartTable attribute : st-select-row="row".
2. after user selects rows and click "add" button the selected data registered to some other list.
3. I don't want to remove added rows from table but I do want them to be not selectable.

This is code example:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="FarmManagment" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <table id="Table" class="table table-hover" st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th st-sort="farmName">Farm Name</th>
    <th st-sort="FarmDescription">Description</th>
    <th st-sort="DataCenter">DC</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
    <td ng-bind="row.farmName">{{row.farmName}}</td>
    <td ng-bind="row.FarmDescription"></td>
    <td ng-bind="row.DataCenter"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
 <button id="add" ng-click="add(displayedCollection)"> add </button>
 <li>
  <ul ng-bind="row.farmName" ng-repeat="row in added"></ul>
 </li>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var app = angular.module('FarmManagment', ['smart-table']);
 app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {


$scope.rowCollection = [
    {farmName: 'farm1', FarmDescription: 'some farm1', DataCenter: 'London'},
    {farmName: 'farm2', FarmDescription: 'some farm2', DataCenter: 'Paris'},
    {farmName: 'farm3', FarmDescription: 'some farm3', DataCenter: 'Berlin'}
];

$scope.added = [];



$scope.add = function(rows){
  angular.forEach(rows,function(row){
    if (row.isSelected === true){
      row.isSelected = false;
      var index = $scope.added.indexOf(row);
      if(index === -1){
      $scope.added.push(row);
      // row.disableSelection    this is what i want to do
      }
    }

  });
};
});
```

How can I implement such behavior?

plunker code:[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UJnWdN?p=preview)

Thanks
Dima

Comment: Hi, can you add a plunker with your code?

Comment: sure creating one, will take some time

Comment: this is plunker example https://plnkr.co/edit/UJnWdN?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add condition like

`<tr st-select-row="isSelectableRow(row)" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">`

and in the controller

```
$scope.isSelectableRow = function (row) {
  if (~$scope.added.indexOf(row))
    return false;
    return row;
}
```

And also, you have incorrect html

```
<li><ul>..</ul></li>
```

change it to

```
<ul><li>..</li></ul>
```

Working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ie6AnHDyMjUJgmFbl0wU)

Answer (score 2):

can be done using the attribute st-select-row:

for example prevent the second row to be selectable

```
<tr st-select-row="$index != 1 ? row : null" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qz6879Ok71fDt6aySHO7?p=preview)